# How can I shade a (decorated) path or let it fade when it crosses a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path, tikz-decorations

There's nothing but a path which crosses a node and then splits into three. When crossing the node, which has some text in it, it should either shade or, even better, fade towards the center of the node and then regain its full color when it leaves the node. `transparency`, `opacity` etc. didn't help.

```
% uses-*- MODE: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[main=latin]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta,
  automata, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.shapes,
  decorations.text, fadings, patterns}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella X}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{x=.7cm,y=.7cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[align=center, every node/.style={draw, circle},>=stealth]
    \node(Cotta) at (5,5) {C.~Aurelius Cotta};
    \node(Balbus) at (0,0) {Q.~Lucilius Balbus};
    \node(Velleius) at (10,0)  {C.~Velleius};
    \node[minimum width=2](Cicero) at (5,-5) {M.~Tullius Cicero};
    \node[minimum width=2](Lector) at (5, -10) {Lector};
  \end{scope};
  \begin{scope}[every path/.style={black, decorate, decoration={waves}}]
    \draw (Lector) -- (5,-5);
    \draw (5,-5) -- (Balbus) ;
    \draw (5,-5) -- (Cotta) ;
    \draw (5,-5) -- (Velleius);
  \end{scope};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the example from the manual, you can declare a fading based on the radial shading but instead of *real* colors you use the placeholder `transparent`:

```
\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!0, outer color=transparent!100]
```

Then you can use `path fading=fade out, fill=white` on the Cicero node:

```
\node[minimum width=2, path fading=fade out, fill=white]
  (Cicero) at (5, -5) {M.~Tullius Cicero};
```

The waves paths need to put behind this node then which in this case is easiest done via the `on background layer` from the `backgrounds` library.

If the fading isn't to your liking, we will need to implement another shading via [`\pgfdeclareradialshading`](https://tikz.dev/base-shadings#%5Cpgfdeclareradialshading) or use the predefined fadings `circle with fuzzy edge XX percent` where `XX` stands for `10`, `15` or `20` (which are rather harsh).

You might experience different results based on your PDF renderer.

### Code

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[main=latin]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing, backgrounds, fadings}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella X}
\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!0, outer color=transparent!100]
\begin{document}
\tikzset{x=.7cm,y=.7cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[align=center, every node/.style={draw, circle}]
\node(Cotta) at (5,5) {C.~Aurelius Cotta};
\node(Balbus) at (0,0) {Q.~Lucilius Balbus};
\node(Velleius) at (10,0)  {C.~Velleius};
\node[minimum width=2, path fading=fade out, fill=white] % ← add fading
  (Cicero) at (5, -5) {M.~Tullius Cicero};
\node[minimum width=2](Lector) at (5, -10) {Lector};
\end{scope};
\begin{scope}[
  every path/.style={decorate, decoration={waves}},
  on background layer] % ← on background
\draw (Lector) -- (Cicero.center);
\draw (Cicero.center) -- (Balbus) ;
\draw (Cicero.center) -- (Cotta) ;
\draw (Cicero.center) -- (Velleius);
\end{scope};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Alternatively we might want to adapt the decoration to incorporate varying opacity values for a select number of waves.